# How do I centre/center multiple objects vertically and horizontally in XCode's interface builder?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, autolayout, xcode6

So I've set up my constraints:

[image]

In each device these objects are displaying as expected.

**iPhone:**

[image]

**iPad:**
[image]

But not I'd like to control how high up or low down these objects are from the top or bottom of the screen or just centre them. You can see from my screen shot they're not centred horizontally.

**What I've tried:**

When I try to centre them I keep getting those annoying yellow warnings. I even tried to add a view and put the objects inside the view and setup the constraints then centre that view. I still got errors.

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Had a bit more time so i thought I would explain it a little better

1) Select the button / thing you want to position, in my image below it's a button called actions which I want to place to the right someway down the screen

[image]

2) click align from the buttons at the bottom right

[image]

3) choose align "horizontal centre in container" or vertical depending on whether you want to position it vertically or horizontally

[image]

The screen will look something like this, ignore all the complaints in yellow we will fix them later

[image]

4) Choose the newly created constraint from the buttons "size inspector" on the right, select it and edit it

[image]

5) At the top choose the "first item" and select "reverse first and second item" from the pull down menu

[image]

6) Then choose what part of the button you want to align ie leading edge / middle
so far the right side of xcode should look something like this:

[image]

the super view has to still be:

superview.centre X

7) then you can set the multiplier to divide the screen equally or to a percent, ie 0.5 / 1 / 1.5 - quarter way across screen, halfway, 3/4 way across

[image]

You see the number on the yellow constraint has changed

[image]

If you change the multiplier again

[image]

The number will change

[image]

Don't worry that the button hasn't moved, that all happens when you update the view
select the main view and then select "update all frames in view" from the bottom right update menu

[image]

Don't worry if everything else on the screen goes wrong whats important is your button is positioned correctly in this case horizontally in the view (you can at this point do an undo and go back to the point before the update, make a change to the constraint and then update again, then undo and tweak and go round like this until you have it perfect)

[image]

Now I will go back and apply the same method to the vertical alignment and then the same to each button in the view

The important thing is you can set your button position however you want, center / leading etc but you MUST leave the alignment to be the center of the superview if you change it to top or leading it will convert the constraint so only constants work not multipliers

EDIT:
To add constraints you use the red box to constrain the thing to expand and contract to the edges of the device, if you simply want to fix the size of the thing you can use the constraints in the yellow boxes, remember to click the add constraints button at the bottom
[image]

Comment: I will give this a try and report back. I've tried so many other things and can't seem to get my head around it. Centering just one UISwitch works. Centering a view with elements inside doesn't work as expected. I'll report back after I've tried this.

Comment: it took me quite a while to get my head around, seems daft to me, I expected to be able to set it from the side of the superview but everything seems to be driven from offsets from the centre of the superview, if you want me to expand further with more examples let me know but I've used this technique quite a number of times now and it seems to work well :)

Comment: @LondonGuy, was this any use? did it help you in the end?

Comment: I will be giving it a try within the week. Just reading up on auto layout, constraints etc to get a clear understanding as it's really quite confusing to me. The thing that gets to me are the yellow warnings I keep getting.

Comment: Yeah the yellow warnings are a pain, I tend to ignore them until I'm ready to update the view, if I get confused I usually delete all the constraints and start from scratch then work down from the top 1 object at a time adding top left right constraints then moving on to the next also when you look at your complete view you want to make sure that after the constraints are in they are flexible enough to withstand stretching ie change the content hugging of your flexible objects, if you want me to do you an xib and email it you as an example let me know :)

Comment: I've finally got around to testing this. It centres one button fine. If I want to centre a bunch of buttons and textfields would I need to put them in another view and centre the view? or is there a way to centre horizontally but then control how high or low buttons are placed vertically? Also when I do centre just one button it changes the size of the button. So I resize it then use my arrows to centre it again. I then try to update the frame of either the view or the button but it just shrinks it down again.

Comment: @LondonGuy Using the same method i described above you can centre things vertically, just choose vertical centre in container; follow the same method, check point 7 which explains about using a multiplier to space the thing proportionally across the screen. The button size should be set automatically by the system based on the text size and your content hugging settings, you can fix its size by setting its width and height constraints. if you can please can you up mark me or mark me as correct because I'm new and trying to build reputation :)

Comment: @LondonGuy you want me to email you a example XIB? :)

Comment: It's working for me but the problem is the width of the UITextField. It looks fine in IB but when I build and run the app the UITextfield shrinks.

Comment: @LondonGuy Thanks for the correct answer! thats my first ever! :) cheers! the box will shrink to the size of the text unless you set the width constraint on the text field. if there is other stuff next to it that is squashing it you need to set its content compression resistance priority or content hugging priority, there is lots of stuff on this on the web but the way i remember it is if i want something to compress or expand the i set both these settings to 249 and 749 on the one thats going to be squashed so they are less than the other ones squashing it, does that make sense?

Comment: @LondonGuy  The thing that squashes or expands in any direction must be less than the others horizontally or vertically, and if you have lots of yellow warnings its probably because you have them all set the same and its not flexible enough to expand or contract to the device, vertically in every column of things and horizontally in every row of things one should always be set to less than the others and this is the one that will expand or contract :), hope this makes sense? :)

Comment: No problem. I finally get how to centre things now. The only issues now is setting fixed width. I don't have anything on either side of the text field. As you said the text field has shrunken to the size of the place holder text inside it. I have zero warnings. Can you point me to an article or some where that shows how to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: glad to see you getting the idea :)

Comment: Sorry check my addition to the answer :)

Comment: All working now. Setting the width constraint done the trick.

Comment: Truly amazing, this could be done in a handful of lines of code, by just adjusting the view's frames relative to one another and placing everything in a super view, then centering the super view. Might take 5 minutes. The irony; you can become a constraint master, but it only works with X-Code, every other environment assumes you can do basic math.